# Attemping to dump API info from python into mySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Using python 3 and MySQL.  I am trying to send the API data that I got from python and dump it into MySQL.  Having a really hard time getting past this part.  I want to Create a database in mySQL in python and table that populates  these columns:

formatted_phone_number, name,   website

I keep getting multiple errors so I deleted what I had and starting the last part fresh.

This is what I have so far:

```
import googlemaps
import json
import pprint
import xlsxwriter
import time
import mysql.connector


# Define the API Key.
API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' #I have the API key

# Define the Client
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = API_KEY)

# Do a simple nearby search where we specify the location
# in lat/lon format, along with a radius measured in meters
places_result  = gmaps.places_nearby(location='39.9584061,-75.1465018', radius = 5000, open_now =False , type = 'restaurant')

time.sleep(3)

place_result  = gmaps.places_nearby(page_token = places_result['next_page_token'])

stored_results = []

# loop through each of the places in the results, and get the place details.      
for place in places_result['results']:

    # define the place id, needed to get place details. Formatted as a string.
    my_place_id = place['place_id']

    # define the fields you would liked return. Formatted as a list.
    my_fields = ['name','formatted_phone_number','website']

    # make a request for the details.
    places_details  = gmaps.place(place_id= my_place_id , fields= my_fields)

    # print the results of the details, returned as a dictionary.
    pprint.pprint(places_details['result'])

    # store the results in a list object.
    stored_results.append(places_details['result'])
```

Here is where I'm messing up... I know there is a way to automatically create these tables to fit the API info...

```
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    database="googledb"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE googledb");

mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE rests (formatted_phone_number VARCHAR(255), name VARCHAR(255), website VARCHAR(255))")
sqlFormula = "INSERT INTO rests (formatted_phone_number, name, website) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
```

This is the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dan/Desktop/GoogleAPI/GoogleAPImysql.py", line 49, in 
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 95, in **init**
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 208, in _open_connection
    self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 144, in _do_auth
    self._auth_switch_request(username, password)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 177, in _auth_switch_request
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'googledb'

Comment: And what's the *problem* with what you've posted?

Comment: Please give a [mre] to illustrate the specific issue. What do you mean *"can't seem to"*; errors? Unexpected outputs?

Comment: What do you mean *"messing up"*. What *actually happens?*

Comment: Edited original post to reflect error message.  Sorry, I have covid brain right now

Comment: You include the database in the connection information, *before* the CREATE DATABASE query has run.

Answer (score -1):

Where do you define myDb variable ?
Have you specified the correct configuration for the MySQL instance.
Check IP, check passwords?

The code you are using shows Google API usage. Please include a stacktrace of the error you are seeing from the Python interpreter.

Comment: This isn't an answer. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead.